# videoBG text not showing when video background is enabled

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-plugins, html5-video

I'm working on a wordpress theme, and I'm having an issue I can't seem to fix. I'm using syd lawrences background video - https://github.com/sydlawrence/jquery.videoBG  to apply a video background, but I have some text in the same div and need the text to show, but somehow, the text is not showing up. My website is here - http://digitalmarketingcardiff.com/copperhead/

the video div has a h1 header and description that are not showing up, where am I going wrong? Please help. I've tried applying z-indexes to the text, but still failing :(

Thanks guys. : )

my markup is  - 
`<div id="home-video">
    <h1><span class="red">Ola,</span> im black dahlia!</h1>
    <span class="home-text">This is a....blah blah.</span>
    <p class="home-text"><a href="#work" class="button">Our Work</a></p>
    <div class="home-icon">
    <a href="#work"><i class="icon-cog icon-spin"></i></a>
    </div>

    </div>`

and in my footer the javascript wrapped in document.ready is

`var isTouch = Modernizr.touch;

    if(!isTouch){jQuery('#home-video').videoBG({

    mp4:'http://localhost/copperhead/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/cameraLens.mp4',

    ogv:'http://localhost/copperhead/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/cameraLens.ogg',

    webm:'http://localhost/copperhead/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/cameraLens.webm',

    poster:'http://localhost/copperhead/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/78703.jpg',

    zIndex:-30,

    fullscreen: true

    });

    }`

Comment: you have two elements with id="home-video" rename one and check if it works

Comment: hi Mateusz, thanks, but the second home-video in the document is being generated by videobg plugin, the markup i have above only has one home-video div. If you inspect the dom after it's done, then I can see the 2 home-video divs, but videobg is generating one of them.

Comment: in DOM you can have only one element with some id (doesn't matter who create it). If video plugin call for element with id='home-vide' it will receive the first element with this id. It is strange because if I inspect the DOM and turn off text-align: center in #home-video all text are appear so that why I think the problem is with id.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Mateusz, I dug a bit deeper, and the plugin actually clones the div, that's why there's 2 divs with same ID. In anycase removing align center, helped me solve the problem. I also removed overflow hidden, and found the text in the middle of a 3000 pixel wide div! For anyone else finding this question, for videoBG, you MUST specify a width, else the element will create a huge width div. Also, z-index should be 0, anything negative, and the text elements wont be clickable. My demo has been updated to work as it should.